# Laravel, check if value is in some collection (in blade)

Tags: laravel

I have 2 collections, `$all` have all the values (5), and `$some` has only 2 values. I'm trying to this:
For each value of $all, if that item in the loop is in the $some collection, put the the value of that $some item (something like that) in the input:

```
@foreach($all as $item)
    <div>
        @if(in_array($item->id, $some))
            <input type="number" value="{{ Here I need to put the value of $some where id of some be teh same of $all }}">
        @else
            <input type="number" value="0">
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I don't know how to read and decide all that inside the blade.

EDIT: I was trying something like this:

```
@if(in_array($item->id, $some))
    <input type="number"  value="{{ $some->find($item->id)->value }}">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the specific fields are on `$some`, but you can do what you want (replacing the fields you need to compare or show) like this:

```
@if(in_array($item->id, $some->pluck('id')->toArray()))
    <input type="number" value="{{ $some->where('id', $item->id)->first()->fieldYouWant}}">
@else
    <input type="number" value="0">
@endif
```

Basically, pull the `$some` ids into an array, compare the current looped `$item->id` (from `$all`), and if it hits, pull the specific `$some` object that matched (id from `$some`, and `id` from current `$all` item) and get the value you need from whatever the field you need is called.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was trying to do this on a array of checkboxes input, in case someone needs it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="guides[]" value="{{ $item->id }}"
    {{ in_array($item->id, $some->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'checked' : '' }} >
```